# Magento layered navigation of custom attribute missing in 1.9.3.1

Tags: php, magento, navigation, upgrade, layered

In magento 1.9.3.1 after upgrade from 1.9.2.4, I added some more option value to the custom attribute. But after saving it is not displaying in layered navigation filter in front-end, I tried to create new custom attribute via backend and tried to display but fails. My category is all set to is anchor 'yes'. I included custom attributes to attribute set too.

I checked all the possible ways. Attribute filtering displays with zero results when giving "Filtering with no results". But it does not display with result. I checked with all products. My products have attribute value displayed in product detail page in backend and also in frontend. My products are configurable product.

Please help me.Category filtering is displaying in layered navigation but not custom attribute filtering.

Comment: Can you add some sample code, rather than explaining it?